# Is there a way to remove etters and numbers except 'a' and 'I'

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have a string:

```
'I will g go to a walk d today'
```

I need to convert it into:

```
'I will go to a walk today'
```

I tried to use:

```
re.sub(r'\b[A-Za-z0-9]\b', ' ', 'I will g go to a walk d today')
```

But I am getting:

```
'  will   go to   walk   today'
```

How can I exclude *'I'* and *'a'* from RegEx?

Comment: `\b(?![aI]\b)[A-Za-z0-9]+\b`

Comment: re.sub(r'\b[A-HJ-Zb-z0-9]\b', ' ', v)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code doesn't work.

Comment: it gives:   'I         a      '

Comment: Just remove `+`, it is  a typo, `\b(?![aI]\b)[A-Za-z0-9]\b`. The point is to use a lookahead in your original pattern, it will restrict the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. What if I have a sentence: "i'm still working on here. I will go to a walk today. it's gotta be very soon". How can I prevent deleting 's' and 'm'?

Comment: Add `(?<!\b')` after the first `\b`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. Do I understand correctly that A(?!B) matches the expression A = \b(?<!\b' only if it is not followed by B = [aIi]\b    ?

Comment: `A(?!B)` = match `A` not immediately followed with `B`.